How do I solve 1D inhomogeneous wave equation with piecewise initial condition? D'Alembert's formula?

From: Peter J Olver Introduction to PDEs excercise 2.4.2. (a)
This is from the end of Chapter 2.4 on the wave equation. I'm a bit confused as to how to begin this excercise, and what they've done in the provided solutions. Do I apply D'Alembert's formula $$u(x,t)=\frac{f(x-ct)+f(x+ct)}{2}+\frac 1{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(y)dy+\frac1{2c}\int_{0}^t\int_{x-c(t-s)}^{x+c(t-s)}F(z,s)dzds$$ or am I supposed to reason it through some other way? 
In general, how do I deal with a piecewise initial condition?
